# How to create a Tree for DFS/ BFS

Tags: c++, search, tree

So here is a binary tree if created,[no longer BT] What steps would be necessary to make this into a general tree/dynamically creating children tree which then can perform DFS/BFS?

Edited:
Have added Node Vector for children, am I on the right track? Please keep in mind I will have to dynamically generate children of a char array(or int array), (not like how I have hard-coded here).
If I am going about the implementation properly, could you please direct me in a proper way to generate the children dynamically, such that the string "012345678" will have 2 children ("102345678") & ("312045678"), or string "283164705" will have 3 children ("283164075") & ("283104765") & ("283164754").

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
    char data;
    Node *next;
};

void AddNode(Node *&listpointer, char newdata){
    Node *current;
    current = listpointer;
    if(current != NULL){
        while(current -> next != NULL){
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    Node *temp;
    temp = new Node;
    temp->data = newdata;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if(current != NULL){
        current->next = temp;
    }
    else{
        listpointer = temp;
    }
}

void PrintLL(Node *&listpointer)
{   
    Node *temp;
    temp = listpointer;
    if(temp == NULL){return;}

    int element = 1;
    while(true){
        if(temp == NULL) break;

        cout << "Element " << element << " is: " << temp->data <<endl;
        temp = temp->next;
        element++;
    }
    cout <<"End of list"<<endl;
}


class Tree{
    private:
        vector<Node *> children;

    public:
        Tree(){}
        ~Tree(){}

        void AddChild(Node *child);
        void PrintChildren();
        vector<Node *> GetChildren(){return children;}
};

void Tree::AddChild(Node *child){
    children.push_back(child);
}

void Tree::PrintChildren(){
    int i = 1;
    for(int j = 0; j < children.size(); j++){
        cout << "Child # " << i << ": " <<children[j]->data<<endl;
        i++;
    }
}

Tree *T1, *T2;
Node *A, *B, *C, *D;

int main(){

    AddNode(A, 'a');
    AddNode(B, 'b');
    AddNode(C, 'c');
    AddNode(D, 'd');

    T1 = new Tree();

    T1->AddChild(A);
    T1->AddChild(B);
    T1->AddChild(C);
    T1->AddChild(D);
    T1->PrintChildren();

}
```

Comment: Do you need to change the tree or change the traversal algorithm?  I always thought it was the traversal algorithm that changed, not the data structure.

Comment: The tree is fine for things such as in-order traversal and such but I need to change the behavior so it can generate children from one starting tree. A little bit more information; The starting tree will have a string i.e. "012345678", I need for it to generate children -> "123045678" and "102345678" etc.

Comment: In general, I recommend you review containers (i.e. BST is a container).  You should notice that after you declare a container (such as vector<Something>), then code development continues by using methods of that container, in particular to add elements (push_back), remove elements (pop_back), inspect or search  etc.   For your BST 'container' such methods (with different names) are required.  The main idea is:  instantiate a BST, then add method to add elements, and add will need to use some sort order.  The Methods Find or display will use the same key.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I cannot use a BST as a Tree because when searching through the tree, generation of 3 or 4 children is to be expected (maximum of 4). This is where I am having most of the trouble, how can I turn the above BST into a general tree? Would it be sensible to just add 2 more pointers to this implementation?

Comment: Just replace*leftptr and *rightptr with an `std::vevtor`of pointers (or even better a vector of `std::unique_ptr`